# How can I do java regex? Match 2-3 letters?

Tags: java

I have problem with my java project, I did not add match combination, I have a dictionary and mixed, dictionary is havenormal word, in mixed changed from dictionary like; in dic. = "mouse" mixed= "usemo" those are the same word, I want to do If I write on mixed "usmo" program go to the dictionary and 4 letters are the same at dictionary so word is mouse, or mixed = "usem" dictionary can change "mouse", I search this can be possible with regex, but I do not any idea about how to do this, can anybody help me??

Comment: Yes, you can do this with lookaheads.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the running code which will match with the pattern that you search using regex and print the matching result from the dictionary.

```
   public class RegexTestStrings {

    private static HashSet<String> dictionarySet = new HashSet<String>();
    private static HashSet<String> regExSetSet = new HashSet<String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dictionarySet.add("mouse");
        dictionarySet.add("tiger");
        dictionarySet.add("monkey");
        RegexTestStrings regexTestStrings=new RegexTestStrings();
        System.out.println(regexTestStrings.fidMatchingWord(dictionarySet,"usemo"));
        System.out.println(regexTestStrings.fidMatchingWord(dictionarySet,"usem"));
        System.out.println(regexTestStrings.fidMatchingWord(dictionarySet,"usmo"));
        System.out.println(regexTestStrings.fidMatchingWord(dictionarySet,"kmoy"));
    }

    private String fidMatchingWord(HashSet<String> dictionarySet2, String searchWord) {
        String result=null;
        Iterator<String> dictionarIterator=dictionarySet.iterator();
        while(dictionarIterator.hasNext()){
            regExSetSet.clear();
            String inputString=dictionarIterator.next();
            findAllRegEx(inputString.toCharArray(), 0, inputString.length()-1);
            Iterator<String> resultIterator=regExSetSet.iterator();
            // Regular expression to match the pattern of search string
            String pattern = "(?s)^(" + Pattern.quote(searchWord) + ".*$|.*" + Pattern.quote(searchWord) + ")$";
            while(resultIterator.hasNext()){
                String str=resultIterator.next();
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
                Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
                boolean b = m.matches();
                if(b){
                    result=inputString;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void findAllRegEx(char[] ary, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        if(startIndex == endIndex){
            regExSetSet.add(String.valueOf(ary));
        }else{
            for(int i=startIndex;i<=endIndex;i++) {
                 swap(ary, startIndex, i );
                 findAllRegEx(ary, startIndex+1, endIndex);
                 swap(ary, startIndex, i );
            }
        }
    }

    public static void swap(char[] arr, int x, int y) {
        char temp = ary[x];
        arr[x] = arr[y];
        arr[y] = temp;
    }   
}
Output
______________
mouse
mouse
mouse
monkey
```

Comment: ı tried this but, is there a like function? because my program is not short like this there are lot's of word inmy program.

Comment: I mean 3 letters are equal okay, change from dictionary.

Comment: @FurkanKesgin , If you are looking for  `like` function of SQL then in Java  `.*` will match any characters in REGEX which i have used above in the pattern.You have to modify the above program to support your requirement. I believe the answer is satisfying the  question that you asked originally.If you are facing another issue then create a new question and explain the problem.